# Dividing a bit string into three parts in C

Tags: c, bit, bitstream

I currently have a integer value that was read from an input file as a hexadecimal. I need to divide the 32 bit bitstream into three separate parts in order to manipulate it. The desired output is below:

desired output:

[image]

In this, V is my input value, left is the first X1 digits, next is the digits between X1 and X2, and last is the digits from X2 to the end. There is a constraint that each subsection must be greater than 0 in length.

What makes this difficult is that the location where I am splitting x varies (X1 and X2 can change)

Is there a good way to split these up?

Comment: Shift the appropriate number of places and mask the result with a number with as many ones bits as you want? e.g. `x & 7` to get low bits 0–2, `x >> 4 & 15` to get bits 4–7…

Comment: Im confused on where you got 7 which results in bits 0-2 and 4-15 which results in bits 4-7?

Comment: 7 is 111 in binary. 15 is 1111. 0–2 is 3 bits and 4–7 is 4 bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `splitter()` function here does the job you ask for.  It takes quite a lot of arguments, unfortunately.  There's the value to be split (`value`), the size of the chunk at the least significant end of the value (`p1`), the size of the middle chunk (`p2`), and then pointers to the high, medium and low values (`hi_val`, `md_val`, `lo_val`).

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void splitter(uint32_t value, unsigned p1, unsigned p2, uint32_t *hi_val, uint32_t *md_val, uint32_t *lo_val)
{
    assert(p1 + p2 < 32);
    *lo_val = value & ((1U << p1) - 1);
    value >>= p1;
    *md_val = value & ((1U << p2) - 1);
    value >>= p2;
    *hi_val = value;
}

static void test_splitter(uint32_t value, int p1, int p2)
{
    uint32_t hi_val;
    uint32_t md_val;
    uint32_t lo_val;

    splitter(value, p1, p2, &hi_val, &md_val, &lo_val);
    printf("0x%.8" PRIX32 " (%2u,%2u,%2u) = 0x%.4" PRIX32 " : 0x%.4" PRIX32 " : 0x%.4" PRIX32 "\n",
            value, (32 - p1 - p2), p2, p1, hi_val, md_val, lo_val);
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t value;

    value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    test_splitter(value, 9, 11);
    value = 0xFFF001FF;
    test_splitter(value, 9, 11);
    value = 0x000FFE00;
    test_splitter(value, 9, 11);

    value = 0xABCDEF01;
    test_splitter(value, 10, 6);
    test_splitter(value, 8, 8);
    test_splitter(value, 13, 9);
    test_splitter(value, 10, 8);

    return 0;
}
```

The `test_splitter()` function allows for simple testing of a single value plus the sections it is to be split in, and `main()` calls the test function a number of times.

The output is:

```
0xFFFFFFFF (12,11, 9) = 0x0FFF : 0x07FF : 0x01FF
0xFFF001FF (12,11, 9) = 0x0FFF : 0x0000 : 0x01FF
0x000FFE00 (12,11, 9) = 0x0000 : 0x07FF : 0x0000
0xABCDEF01 (16, 6,10) = 0xABCD : 0x003B : 0x0301
0xABCDEF01 (16, 8, 8) = 0xABCD : 0x00EF : 0x0001
0xABCDEF01 (10, 9,13) = 0x02AF : 0x006F : 0x0F01
0xABCDEF01 (14, 8,10) = 0x2AF3 : 0x007B : 0x0301
```

If any of the sections is larger than 16, the display gets spoiled — but the code still works.

In theory, the `1U` values could be a 16-bit quantity, but I'm assuming that the CPU is working with 32-bit `int`.  There are ways (`UINT32_C(1)`) to ensure that it is a 32-bit value, but that's probably OTT.  The code explicitly forces 32-bit unsigned integer values, and prints them as such.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want to allocate data. Look `alloca` `malloc` fucntions.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's what is required at all.